# Using Excel VBa to send Outlook e-mails

Tags: vba, excel, outlook-2010

I'm developing an Excel macro to send e-mails to specific customers.  The code I have so far works pretty well.  This is the first macro I've done with Outlook.  The issue I'm having is with the DETAIL_INFO variable.  The detail info should have 2 columns: (1) for customer information and (2) for invoice information.  There will be 4 or 5 fields in each column.  What I'm trying to do is have some verbiage at the begging of the e-mail and then display the invoice information in 2 columns.  I'd like a separate section for each invoice.  There could be 1 invoice or there could be multiple invoices.  Once the invoice information is displayed, then there is some additional verbiage.

Can this be done?  Below the code is some sample results.  Thanks for the help...

```
strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
    Date & "<br><br>" & _
    VarB & " " & VarC & "<br>" & _
    Add1 & "<br>" & _
    Add2 & ", " & Add3 & "    " & Add4 & "<br><br><br>" & _
    "Dear Customer,<br><br>" & _
    "Thank you for choosing us.<br><br>" & _
    "We appreciate your business.  At times, we follow up with customers<br>" & _
    "to minimize confusion.<br><br>" & _
    "Please see below for more details:<br><br><br>" & _
    DETAIL_INFO & "<br>" & _
    "<br><br><br>Our goal is to handle these situations as promptly as possible." & _
   "Again, we appreciate the opportunity to serve you.<br><br>" & _
    "Sincerely,<br>" & _
    "ABC Company"
```

Results:

blah blah blah

Contact Info                              Invoice Info
First Name:  Joe                          Invoice ID:    12345
Last Name:   Smith                        Invoice Date:  05/15/2015
City:        Kansas City                  Invoice Amt:   15.00
State:       MO                           Due Date:      06/15/2015

Contact Info # 2                          Invoice Info  # 2
First Name:  Bill                         Invoice ID:    11223
Last Name:   Jones                        Invoice Date:  05/25/2015
City:        Kansas City                  Invoice Amt:   25.00
State:       MO                           Due Date:      06/25/2015

Thanks again for your help.......

Comment: How is the "DETAIL_INFO" variable created?  That code is more relevant than the code you provided.

Comment: At any rate, I'd create it using HTML tables.  See here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: can you add an image of what your email body should look like.

Comment: @OpiesDad......This is my first attempt at creating the Detail_Info variable.  It a loop that cycles through the data for all lines for a particular customer.  Detail_Info = "Member ID:" & VarA & Chr(10)
        Detail_Info = "Member First Name:" & VarB & Chr(10)
        Detail_Info = "Member Last Name:" & VarC & Chr(10)
        Detail_Info = "Trip ID:" & VarL

Comment: @Omar...I have an image but do not know how to add it to this thread.  thanks.......

Comment: You may find this helpful: [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Ron de Bruin's site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) for great ways of creating emails. The linked page shows how to get Excel to do the hard work of turning a range into an HTML email.

Comment: @Chipsletten.............I found information there that helped resolve the issue.  Thanks for pointing that out.